# jqgrid - close form dialog

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid 4.3.1 and I am using form editing with local data. The problem is the form does not close after adding or editing. Here is my code.

```
                  $('#studentset').jqGrid({
                      data: mydata,
                      datatype: "local",
                      colNames:['id','First Name', 'Last Name'], 
                      colModel:[ 
                                   {name:'id',index:'id', width:60}, 
                                   {name:'firstName',index:'fName', width:300, editable:true},
                                   {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:300, editable:true}
                      ],
                      pager: '#pager',
                      rowNum: 10,
                      rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                      sortname: 'id',
                      sortorder: 'asc',
                      viewrecords: true,
                      height: "80%",
                      caption: "Students to be Registered",
                      editurl: corpUrl
                  });
                  $('#studentset').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: true, del: false, search: false, refresh: false },
                            {
                                recreateForm: true,
                                closeAfterEdit: true,
                                modal:true,
                                afterSubmit: function(data){
                                    var myObject = eval('(' + data.responseText + ')');
                                    $('#studentset').setGridParam({data: myObject}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                recreateForm: true,
                                closeAfterAdd: true,
                                modal:true,                 
                                afterSubmit: function(data){
                                    var myObject = eval('(' + data.responseText + ')');
                                    $('#studentset').setGridParam({data: myObject}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                                }
                            },
                            {},{},{}      
                    );
```

Notice in the edit and add options of the navGrid I have specified the relevant options. `closeAfterAdd: true,` and `closeAfterEdit: true`. But the modal form simply refuses to close. I am not sure if its a bug in this version of jqgrid.

Can someone please offer some guidance? May be, how to close the dialog manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so its logical, simply trigger the click event of the dialog close button like this. You will find the ID of the span tag using fire bug.

```
                  $('#studentset').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: true, del: false, search: false, refresh: false },
                            {
                                modal:true,
                                jqModal: true,
                                afterSubmit: function(data){
                                    var myObject = eval('(' + data.responseText + ')');
                                    $('#studentset').setGridParam({data: myObject}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                                    $(".ui-icon-closethick").trigger('click');
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                modal:true,
                                jqModal: true,
                                afterSubmit: function(data){
                                    var myObject = eval('(' + data.responseText + ')');
                                    $('#studentset').setGridParam({data: myObject}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                                    $(".ui-icon-closethick").trigger('click');
                                }
                            },
                            {},{},{}      
                    );
```

Hope someone benefits from this.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that if you have any other dialog boxes open, they will also be closed.  The reason is that you aren't triggering on the ID of the span, you are triggering on the class of the span and they will be sharing a class by default.

Comment: Can you explain what these 2 lines do?      var myObject = eval('(' + data.responseText + ')');
                                    $('#studentset').setGridParam({data: myObject}).trigger("reloadGrid");   Sorry about the crappy formatting.

Comment: data.responseText is json data that must be evaluated into a javascript object. This will be the new data which will be shown after the reload.

Comment: joseph, I can uniquely identify the form and hence its close link as the grid has a unique ID so it will be something like $("#uniqueGridId uniqueFormId .ui-icon-closethick").trigger('click');

Answer (score 7):

according to the documentaion, the syntax of **afterSubmit** is:

```
afterSubmit : function(response, postdata) 
{ 
 … 
return [success,message,new_id] 
}
```

otherwise IE8 will throw error eventhough data successfully posted.

you can use:

```
return [true,'',''];
```

then **closeAfterAdd:true** and **closeAfterEdit:true** will work without the need to programmatically closing the form:

```
$('#cData').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with the help of bootstrap, the idea of placing the jqgrid in a div and then close the div with a link serves the purpose. Following is the code.

```
 <div>
<div class="alert alert-default">
<a href="#" id="okayMessage" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" 
 aria-label="close">&times;</a>
 <br>
   <table id="accountIdSearch" style="font-size: 11px"></table>
        <div id="pagingDivId" style="height: 50px;">
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding a large framework like Bootstrap for this purpose only does not make a lot of sense. OP is using only jQuery, everything else is speculation. Try to reflect that in your answer.