# closeAfterEdit not working after editing the form jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using jqgrid and the only issue is Edit form is not closed after editing, whereas Add form and Delete form are closed and reloaded properly. I think I am giving the options order incorrectly but I tried different permutations but no luck. Can anyone give a look at my javascript and provide any suggestions?

```
$("#person").jqGrid('navGrid', '#personpager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true },
           { closeAfterEdit:true, reloadAfterSubmit: true },
           { closeAfterAdd:true, reloadAfterSubmit: true },
           { reloadAfterSubmit: true },
           { closeOnEscape:true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true },
           {});
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be a bug in jqGrid version you are using, BTW what is the version you are using...anyways

look at this solution i think this is exactly what you need

[jqgrid - close form dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077864/jqgrid-close-form-dialog)

Comment: I am using jqGrid 4.4.0. So, you think it might be a bug? It's so strange. I looked at your link earlier before posting this question and thought there might be an easy way out. But if it is a bug, then I will try this and see how it goes. Thank you so much!

Comment: well in 4.4.0, it should not be a bug....there might be something wrong you are writing with your code, as i can not look at you complete code. If you let me look at your code, i may help you. skype screen sharing or sth?

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this after trying every place I could possibly add `closeAfterEdit: true`.  I had defined formatoptions in my colModel to open modal for edit; looks like `formatoptions.editoptions` was the place I needed to set the value:

> ```
> colModel: [...{
>                   name: 'Edit',
>                   search: false,
>                   width: 60,                  
>                   sortable: false,
>                   edittype: 'button',
>                   formatter: 'actions',
>                   formatoptions: {
>                       editformbutton: true,
>                       editOptions: {
>                           **closeAfterEdit: true**
>                       },
>                       delOptions: {
>                           ... 
>                           },
>                           onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
>                               var rowData = $(this).getRowData(postdata);
>                               return { TagId: rowData.TagId };
>                           }
>                       }
>                   },
>                   title: false
>               },
> ```